# nested fields for generated twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

The following form is meant to edit a number of related records simultaneously, while formatting the number of records based on `in_groups_of`.

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <div class='row'>
    <% @event.eventdistances.in_groups_of(6, false) do |eventdistances| %>
      <%= f.fields_for :eventdistances do |eventdistance| %>
        <div class='small-2 medium-2 large-2 columns'>
          <%= eventdistance.check_box :active %> <%= eventdistance.object.building.nome %><br /><%= number_with_precision(eventdistance.object.distance, precision: 1) %> km
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

However, the html beng generated is not closing the row tags after a group of 6, and the whole shebang is rendered twice.

do `in_groups_of` and `fields_for` conflict somehow because if I remove the `in_groups_of`tag, only one complete version is rendered?

How can this be resolved properly?

Comment: I think the root of the problem is that `fields_for` is intended to work with an association while `in_groups_of` is a method from the stdlib Enumerable module that splits the relation object into arrays.

Comment: However I think that you're approaching the problem wrong. If you want the items in a responsive grid you don't want to add the rows manually. Instead you just shove them into a box with a width of 12 and let it flow depending on the display size.

Comment: actually this is happening right now already if I remove the `in_groups_of` tag (foundation grid), it is flowing, but not to perfection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <% @event.eventdistances.in_groups_of(6, false) do |eventdistances| %>
    <div class='row'>
      <%= f.fields_for :eventdistances, eventdistances do |eventdistance| %>
        <div class='small-2 medium-2 large-2 columns'>
          <%= eventdistance.check_box :active %> <%= eventdistance.object.building.nome %><br /><%= number_with_precision(eventdistance.object.distance, precision: 1) %> km
       </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The first problem what that when you call `f.fields_for :eventdistances do |eventdistance|` its calling `f.object.eventdistances` (f.object = @event) and not using the local variable as you are expecting. Thats why it repeats all the records six times.

What you want to do is pass the collection as the second argument. Also if you want to put each group into a `<div class='row'>` you want to place the tag inside the block passed to `.in_groups_of`.